# Web api routing in subfolder application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a main site running under `example.com`. Now I'm creating a application into  `example.com` subfolder like `example.com/subfolder/subsite/`, so I have created a application in the `subsite` folder and everything is working fine, except the routes.

I have the following route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("myapi", "api/{controller}/{hash}", defaults: new { hash = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

The route is working fine if I'm debuging the API in localhost or hosting it somewhere else in the root, but it's not working when running inside the `subsite` application folder.

Any tips?

Comment: Can you run the site in an application folder which is not in the tree of another?  Alternatively, don't have separate applications.  One application folder = one application.

Comment: The site works fine if it is not in the tree of another. I don't have access to the parent application.

Comment: did you really create a new web application instead of just a virtual sub directory? Just asking  because I just tested it, create a simple api controller which returns a string and create a /test site in a /test/sub site, both running the same web api project. And it simply works

Comment: I'm gonna tet it again. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you really create a new web application instead of just a virtual sub directory?

I just tested it, create a simple api controller which returns a string and create a /test site in a /test/sub site, both running the same web api project. 
And it simply works.

If this is not the issue, please provide more details... error msg etc...